# My Django Home Page @ Amazon is Returning 'Index of/'

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am done with a Django project I have been working on and the day I dread when I switched from PHP to Python is now upon me - **Deploying**. I always had the feeling that it won't be easy deploying and having Django app work. I used `eb deploy` my Django app to elasticbeanstalk environment but when I open `mysite.elasticbeanstalk.com` I get **Index of/**

---

**mysite.config:**

```
container_commands:   
  01_syncdb:    
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  install_MySQL-python:
        command: /opt/python27/run/venv/bin/easy_install MySQL-Python==1.2.4

option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles
      option_name: WSGIPath
      value: mysite/wsgi.py
    - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
      value: mysite.settings
    - option_name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
      value: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    - option_name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      value: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I have also tried `command: "manage.py syncdb --noinput"` but it is not working.

**folder structure:**

```
.ebextensions/
   mysite.config
.elasticbeanstalk/
   config
manage.py
mysite/
   __init__.py
   settings.py
   urls.py
   wsgi.py
requirements.txt
```

When I check through the error log this is what I get:

```
-------------------------------------
/opt/python/log/httpd.out
-------------------------------------




-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Mon Mar 09 12:38:02.208709 2015] [suexec:notice] [pid 6157] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Mar 09 12:38:02.259728 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 6157] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Mar 09 12:38:02.260895 2015] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 6157] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Mar 09 12:38:02.261027 2015] [:warn] [pid 6157] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.5.
[Mon Mar 09 12:38:02.261044 2015] [:warn] [pid 6157] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.8.
[Mon Mar 09 12:38:02.328774 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6157] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 09 12:38:02.328851 2015] [core:notice] [pid 6157] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong for the past five days.